# How could I keep paragraph format using CKeditor4.4.4 in CodeIgniter?

Tags: javascript, html, codeigniter, ckeditor, django-ckeditor

I'm currently using an inline CKEditor 4.4.4 in CodeIniter. How can I keep paragraph format when I use CKEditor for inserting data into database and receive it back?

Here is my JavaScript code with CKEditor plugin and configure:

```
<script>
CKEDITOR.inline('skill', {
    toolbar: [
        { name: 'document', groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ], items: [ 'Source', '-', 'Save','Preview', 'Print' ] },
        { name: 'clipboard', groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ], items: [ 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo','Image', 'Flash', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'Smiley', 'SpecialChar', 'PageBreak','Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize' ] },
        '/', 
        { name: 'clipboard', groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ], items: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat','NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', 'CreateDiv', '-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock', '-', 'BidiLtr', 'BidiRtl'] },
    ]
});
</script>
```

And here is HTML form

```
<li>
    <span class="cvspan">Description:</span><?php echo form_textarea('we_dis',set_value('skill',$property->skill));?>
</li>
```

[image]

When I submit the text into database and get result without format and text show as images 2

[image]

Comment: I guess all formatting is escaped before inserting/updating to database or when showing in Editor.

Comment: Could your compare html of both cases?

Comment: @Vahan Vardanyan, You are right because Codeigniter clean string before insert data into database and I used this rules:

`'rules' => 'trim|required|xss_clean'`
and about HTML tag I used try to used simple div and without added other HTML tag to it but it still not working for me But if I don't use Codeigniter to clean string my website will not security so How could I do now

Comment: I think you can configure how this rule applies. Security issues may appear when javascript not escaped, but not simple HTML markup.

Comment: You can write your own validation method. Look [here](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks).

Comment: Yes, But I configue my validation as array like this

`  public  $add_cv_rules =array(
         'title' => array(
            'field' => 'title',
            'label' => 'CV Title',
            'rules' => 'trim|required|xss_clean'
        ), `
and I think it should not clean html tag because all the data that I insert into my database always have `<ul></li>simple text or data</ul></li> and other <ol><li>simple data</li></ol>` and it have some other html tag too but not at all I create in CKeditor and check on **Inspect Element**

Comment: I found all html tag to wrap my data (text) and when I insert to database I see only ul li or ol li and p

Answer (score 0):

Now It is work for me when I make CSS by my self as below code so if someone want to make up their CKeditor on view you should write your own CSS to make up html tag

```
.cke_textarea_inline
        {
            padding:0px;
            min-height:100px;
            height: auto;
            overflow: auto; 
            border: 1px solid gray;
            -webkit-appearance: textfield;
        }
.cke_textarea_inline ol{
    padding-left:2em;
    list-style-position:inside;
    list-style:decimal
}
.cke_textarea_inline ol li{
    padding-left:0em;
    list-style-position:inside;
    list-style:decimal
}
.cke_textarea_inline ol li ol{
    padding-left:2em;
    list-style-position:inside;
    list-style:decimal
}
.cke_textarea_inline ul{
    padding-left:3.2em;
    list-style-position:inside;
    list-style:disc;
}
.cke_textarea_inline ul li{
    padding-left:.8em;
    list-style-position:inside;
    list-style:disc;
}
.cke_textarea_inline ul li ul{
    padding-left:1em;
    list-style-position:inside;
    list-style:disc;
}
.cke_textarea_inline ul li ul li{
    padding-left:.6em;
    list-style-position:inside;
    list-style:disc;
}
```